Undefined property: stdClass::$donate_amount
When the payment is completed, and the amount is deducted, the system is expected to return to the site and record the donation. However, this issue occurs intermittently, not consistently.
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-10 mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="wrapper d-block d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-0">{{ __('translation.Invioce Details') }}</h4>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-solid tab-solid-primary mb-0" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a 
                      class="nav-link active"
                      id="info-tab"
                      data-toggle="tab"
                      href="#info"
                      role="tab"
                      aria-controls="info"
                      aria-expanded="true"
                    >{{ __('translation.Payment Invioce Id') }}: {{ $transaction->invoice_id }}</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a
                      class="nav-link active"
                      id="info-tab"
                      data-toggle="tab"
                      href="#info"
                      role="tab"
                      aria-controls="info"
                      aria-expanded="true"
                    >{{ __('translation.Transaction Id') }} : {{ $transaction->transactionId }}</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a
                      class="nav-link"
                      id="security-tab"
                      data-toggle="tab"
                      href="#security"
                      role="tab"
                      aria-controls="security"
                    >{{ __('translation.Donated Amount') }} : {{ $transaction->donate_amount }} KD</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>


<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-10 mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="wrapper d-block d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-0">{{ __('translation.Invioce Details') }}</h4>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-solid tab-solid-primary mb-0" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a
                      class="nav-link active"
                      id="info-tab"
                      data-toggle="tab"
                      href="#info"
                      role="tab"
                      aria-controls="info"
                      aria-expanded="true"
                    >{{ __('translation.Payment Invioce Id') }}: {{ $transaction->invoice_id }}</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a
                      class="nav-link active"
                      id="info-tab"
                      data-toggle="tab"
                      href="#info"
                      role="tab"
                      aria-controls="info"
                      aria-expanded="true"
                    >{{ __('translation.Transaction Id') }} : {{ $transaction->transactionId }}</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a
                      class="nav-link"
                      id="security-tab"
                      data-toggle="tab"
                      href="#security"
                      role="tab"
                      aria-controls="security"
                    >{{ __('translation.Donated Amount') }} : {{ $transaction->donate_amount }} KD</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
